# Post image into Slack using Incoming Webhook C#

Tags: c#, json, webhooks, slack-api

I'm trying to post a image into slack but I'm having some trouble. Currently I create a httpWebRequest to post the message into slack and use a JavaScriptSerializer to serialize my message into a json formatted string like so:

```
    string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
            {
                username = userName,
                image_url = imageUrl,
                text = message,
                icon_emoji = icon,
                channel = channelName
            });
            streamWriter.Write(json);
```

I'm now trying to add an image to the message but so far have been unsuccessful. I tried adding an attachment like Slack suggusted but I don't think I'm formatting it right. I've tried

```
string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
            {
                username = userName,
                image_url = imageUrl,
                text = message,
                icon_emoji = icon,
                channel = channelName,
                attachments = new {image_url = www.myurllink.com}
            });
            streamWriter.Write(json);
```

Even though the string seems to be set up correctly it fails to post my image, or any other information I include in the slack attachment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I got the answer, I needed to create a new array object then set that array equal to a new element of image_url.

```
string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
            {
                username = userName,
                text = message,
                icon_emoji = icon,
                channel = channelName,
                attachments = new []{ new {image_url = "www.imageurl.com", title = "image as of " + DateTime.Now}}
            });
```

I added the title as well to show how to add multiple elements. You don't need to declare a new element for each item you want to add to the attachment. Just separate it with commas.

Comment: Accept your own answer?

Comment: What if you have multiple images to attach?